# Smooth transition of data in a polar chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have js code that plots a simple polar chart in the HTML page. I am trying to have it update the data on the plot every 1 second.
I was able to update the data and plot the new points, however, there are two things I have not figured out yet.
Right now every second I am cleaning the plot area and plotting everything new, instead I would like to update the data by creating a smooth sliding transition from the previous position to the new one.
The second issue is that the labeling of the points is not being deleted with the old point position, which creates multiple labeling on top of each other.
What should I add in order to create this smooth transition for the plotted points and their labels?

Here is my code snippet:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='ISO-8859-1'>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body style='background-color:lightgray'>
  <div id="chart" style='width: 400px; height: 400px; padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;'></div>

  <script>
    var color = d3.scale.category20();
    var deg2rad = Math.PI / 180;
    var width = 400,
      height = 350,
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - 30;

    var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    var r = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([90, 0])
      .range([0, radius]);

    var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
      .radius(function(d) {
        return r(d[1]);
      })
      .angle(function(d) {
        return -d[0] + Math.PI / 2;
      });

    var gr = null;

    createSkyplot();

    updateSkyPlot();

    function createSkyplot() {
      //////////////////////     
      gr = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "r axis")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(r.ticks(5))
        .enter().append("g");

      gr.append("circle").attr("r", r).style('fill', 'white');

      gr.append("text")
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return -r(d) - 4;
        })
        .attr("transform", "rotate(20)")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style('fill', 'blue')
        .text(function(d) {
          return d;
        });
      /////////////////////

      /////////////////////
      var ga = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "a axis")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(d3.range(0, 360, 45))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "rotate(" + (d - 90) + ")";
        });

      ga.append("line").attr("x2", radius).style('stroke', 'black').style('stroke-dasharray', '1,8');

      ga.append("text")
        .attr("x", radius + 6)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d < 360 && d > 90 ? "end" : null;
        })
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return d < 360 && d > 90 ? "rotate(180 " + (radius + 3) + ",0)" : null;
        })
        .text(function(d) {
          return d + "°";
        });
      /////////////////////
    }

    function updateSkyPlot() {
      var pos = [{
        "position": [1, Math.random() * 20, Math.random() * 20],
        "label": 1
      }, {
        "position": [3, Math.random() * 20, Math.random() * 20],
        "label": 5
      }];

      var r = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([90, 0])
        .range([0, radius]);

      var line = d3.svg.line.radial()
        .radius(function(d) {
          return r(d[1]);
        })
        .angle(function(d) {
          return -d[0] + Math.PI / 2;
        });

      svg.selectAll('circle').remove();

      gr.append("circle").attr("r", r).style('fill', 'white');

      var points = svg.selectAll("point")
        .data(pos)
        .enter()
        .append("a") // The container
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          var coors = line([d.position]).slice(1).slice(0, -1);
          return "translate(" + coors + ")"
        });

      points.append("circle")
        .attr("class", "point")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
          return color(i);
        });

      points.append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d.label
        })
        .style("font-size", "10")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-4,5)");

      setTimeout(updateSkyPlot, 1000);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Code can also be seen [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs).

I have tried adding 
`svg.selectAll("label").remove();` or `svg.selectAll('point.label').remove();`
but it does not work and when i add `svg.selectAll("text").remove();` it removes all the text in the plot which is obviously something i don't want.

Any help on fixing those issues would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I have managed to partially solve the issue. I am using `svg.selectAll('text.label').remove();` to remove the unwanted text inside the circles.